# IEndpointBehavior ApplyClientBehavior method not executed after behavior added to Endpoint Behaviors

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

Given these two classes:

```
public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public MessageInspector MessageInspector;

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters){}
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher){}
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint){}

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        MessageInspector = new MessageInspector();
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(MessageInspector);
    }
}

public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public string LastRequestXML { get; private set; }
    public string LastResponseXML { get; private set; }
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        LastResponseXML = reply.ToString();
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        LastRequestXML = request.ToString();
        return request;
    }
}
```

And this behavior initialization code:

```
var requestInterceptor = new InspectorBehavior();
MYSoapClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(requestInterceptor);
```

Why is it that `ApplyClientBehavior` method is never executed and `MessageInspector` is always null?

Shouldn't `ApplyClientBehavior` be executed when the behavior is added to Endpoint Behavior collection (I verified that it was and that requestInterceptor variable is not null) ?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I got this issue using wcf for .net core.

When I was setting the EndpointBehaviors property after the creation of the wcf client, the method ApplyClientBehavior was not being called.

What did the trick for me is: I had to set the EndpointBehaviors property inside the wcf client constructor. I can't say the reason why this did the trick though, it simply does not make sense to me, but it worked.

You can create a new partial class and have a new constructor to register this behavior if needed. This may be useful in case you need to regenerate the service contract.

Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try when I get a chance.

Comment: This hint helped me after searching for hours why is it not working. Thanks!